# Resize window to fit document size

Tags: javascript, air

I have a `<canvas>` based game which I want to port to Air. The `<canvas>` is `480x480`, now I want to make the window size fit to the canvas, normally one would do this with `innerWidth` and `innerHeight`. Even though air changes the values of both properties, the window size remains unchanged.

Of course, I could just specify the application size as `480x480`, but unfortunately this includes the window chrome(title bar etc.), so it will break as soon as someone on another system runs it, and I don't want scrollbars to overlay my game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, apparently the normal DOM interface isn't good enough for Adobe so they had to do their own thing here:

```
window.nativeWindow.stage.stageWidth
```

Is the equivalent of `window.innerWidth`, this is hardly documented anywhere, although the documentation mentions both `stage` and `stageHeight`, it never tells one to which objects these properties belong.

Comment: stage.nativeWindow.width = stage.nativeWindow.height = 480;  it's totally documented:  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html